# Таймаут очереди сообщений php

Tags: php, long-poll

Хотелось бы реализовать общение между двумя процессами на сервере через средства php для реализации long-pooling.
Для этой цели php был собран с ключами `--enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg`
Предполагается, что работать это будет следующим образом: пока клиент находится на странице, ему отправляются асинхронные запросы средствами ajax. Скрипт на стороне сервера открывает очередь сообщений с помощью `msg_get_queue`. И слушает её определенное количество времени, например, 2 минуты. После чего процесс отмирает и отправляется новый запрос. При получении же данных, они отправляются клиенту.
Однако, возник ряд вопросов:
-Влияет ли функция set_time_limit на вызов функции receive_messages, или она считается системной, поскольку работает через разделяемую память SysV? Потому что у стандартной функции read_message нет параметра timeout, что очень огорчает.
-Можно ли настроить скрипт выполнять определенные действия перед отключением? Очень бы хотелось "гасить" очередь, которая больше не будет использоваться. Если нет, то можно ли снаружи как-то "отстреливать" очереди, с котрыми ни один процесс долго не работал?
P.S. фреймворки не предлагать.

---

P.P.S. Если вы знаете, что long-poll можно реализовать лучше\проще\удобнее - <strike>можете гордиться этим</strike> то скажите сразу, будет ли этот вариант нагружать сервер, на котором уже крутится инстанс апача и php-машины и насколько удобно интегрировать подобное решение в уже существующую систему.

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему (задачу). То что вы тут написали - бред полнейший.

Comment: Требуется реализовать асинхронное динамическое обновление контента страницы. В качестве одного из вариантов решения рассматриваются функции семафоров php. Отправитель должен оповещать "слушателя" (если открыто несколько вкладок - всех) о совершенном действии. Хочу понять, насколько критично здесь управление ресурсами, то есть, если после использзования ресурс не был закрыт - будет ли у него время, после которого он самоуничтожится? И что можно сделать для того, чтобы описанной выше ситуации не возникло. Также интересно, как можно реализовать ожидание потока не wait'ом

Comment: @ArchDemon ну что, нечего написать? В следующий раз тогда и не надо выпендриваться

Comment: А чем же вас ajax не устроил?

Comment: @ArchDemon ajax служит для передачи данных на сервер\с сервера асинхронно. Но от клиента на сервер и с сервера на клиент. А мне нужно передавать данные о событии, которое вызвал один клиент - другому клиенту. Понятное дело, что ajax'ом я передам данные на сервер, а вот дальше - они должны попасть в другой php-скрипт, который уже через тот же ajax отправит их обратно. Я считаю, что это именно та задача, для которой была создана shared memory.

Comment: Если бы вы сразу написали про общение клиент - клиент, то вам бы быстрее правильно ответили. http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling советую вам прочитать. Для вашей задачи всех лучше бы подошёл web-socket

Comment: Также вам ничего не мешает сделать 2 php скрипта: запись данных на сервер, считывание данных с сервера. И запустить на клиенте ajax через таймер для чтения данных и второй ajax для записи

Comment: @ArchDemon таймер для клиента - нагружает клиент, задержка больше, поэтому long-pooling и был придуман. Что такое сокеты - представляю, вот только для них нужно завозить на сервер дополнительный софт, хотя за статью спасибо. Я же хочу понять, как эту задачу можно решить средствами shared mem, прежде чем переключаться на что-то другое.